# Docker image google/cloud-sdk gcloud builds submit command failed with error gcloud crashed (FileNotFoundError)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I am using Docker Image 'google/cloud-sdk' and in the container I use the command `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my-project/my-repo`.

But this command causes the next error `ERROR: gcloud crashed (FileNotFoundError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './proc/42/task/42/fdinfo/5'`.

I also use the command `gcloud beta run deploy` and this is success.

If anyone knows this problem, please tell me about it.

Environment
google/cloud-sdk:278
Authentication: `gcloud auth activate-service-account ~`

```
# gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 278.0.0
alpha 2020.01.24
app-engine-go 
app-engine-java 1.9.78
app-engine-python 1.9.88
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.88
beta 2020.01.24
bigtable 
bq 2.0.52
cbt 
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2020.01.24
datalab 20190610
gsutil 4.47
kubectl 2020.01.24
pubsub-emulator 0.1.0
```

Comment: Could you try to run `gcloud components update` or `gcloud init` to reinitialize the gcloud. Maybe something was wrong with the latest update.

Comment: This image is latest version and can not update. And I also use older image but same thing happened.

Comment: Please include the complete `docker run ...` command to show how you are mounting the `Dockerfile` into the container. The error suggests (for some reason) that `gcloud` is enumerating `/proc` (the container does not include `ps`) to identify files being used by a process (`42`) which is itself curious but, perhaps it's not finding your build's sources?

Answer (score 1):

The error's not ideal (!?) but the following worked for me:

```
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
BILLING=[[YOUR-BILLING]]

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} --billing-account=${BILLING}

gcloud services enable containerregistry.googleapis.com --project=${PROJECT}
gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com --project=${PROJECT}

touch quickstart.sh Dockerfile # Add content etc.

docker run \
--interactive --tty \
--env=CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/config/mygcloud \
--volume=${HOME}/.config/gcloud:/config/mygcloud \
--volume=${PWD}:/59980120 \
google/cloud-sdk gcloud builds submit /59980120 \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--tag=gcr.io/${PROJECT}/freddie
```

Redacted output:

```
Creating temporary tarball archive of 10 file(s) totalling 34.2 KiB before compression.
Uploading tarball of [/59980120] to [gs://...
starting build "7bb29351-e947-408c-9b3b-72fed105b336"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://...
Copying gs://...
/ [1 files][  2.2 KiB/  2.2 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/2.2 KiB.                                      
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  46.59kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
c9b1b535fdd9: Pulling fs layer
c9b1b535fdd9: Verifying Checksum
c9b1b535fdd9: Download complete
c9b1b535fdd9: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ddba4d27a7ffc3f86dd6c2f92041af252a1f23a8e742c90e6e1297bfa1bc0c45
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> e7d92cdc71fe
Step 2/3 : COPY quickstart.sh /
 ---> c76655cf6a85
Step 3/3 : CMD ["/quickstart.sh"]
 ---> Running in b788dcf0de88
Removing intermediate container b788dcf0de88
 ---> 92005e24a933
Successfully built 92005e24a933
Successfully tagged gcr.io/...
PUSH
Pushing gcr.io/...
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/...]
3615e77170c7: Preparing
5216338b40a7: Preparing
5216338b40a7: Layer already exists
3615e77170c7: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:4374028a72533ca5d14b094005ebeb4aa50fe0521738d8508434f0bd3d7a9dc3 size: 735
DONE
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem today and the reason was that I tried to run

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my-project/my-repo.
```

from the root folder of my docker container. I'm not entirely sure what is causing the problem but the fix is quite simple.

In interactive mode, simply `cd` into another directory, for instance:

```
cd /home
```

If you're building a docker image on top of the cloudsdk image, consider setting the `WORKDIR` like this:

```
WORKDIR /home
```